# How do I make game server for UDK game?

Tags: udk, scripting, unreal

I'm new in UDK and I'm starting to develop online multiplayer games.
There is a one problem, I couldn't find any tutorials about how to make a game server using udk. I suppose, that it uses unreal script. But that's about all I know about it.
So I'd really like for some help.

Comment: Are you looking for tutorials or are you looking for someone to tell you all the steps for making a server?

Comment: I need someone to tell all the steps...

Comment: I need to make the client so, that whenever player goes to game, server automatically opens the map in it.
I also need the server to be able to run multiple maps at the same time... So any ideas?

Comment: A server can't run multiple maps at the same time. You can open multiple instances of the UDK and create multiple servers. I'm sure there's a way to set them up on different ports, but I'm not sure how to do that. I really recommend checking out the UDK forums or UDN.

Comment: I already tried to find information from there, but I cant find what Im lookin for

Comment: see this vid http://youtu.be/iQN2D7LJn7w
it is a full tutorial on servers by me and it will work

Answer (score 5):

To launch a dedicated global server, run:

```
UDK.exe server yourmap
```

For a listen server, launch the game with your desired map as normal and append `?listen`:

```
UDK.exe yourmap?listen
```

For a lan server, append `?lan` to the map name (e.g. `UDK.exe server yourmap?lan`)

To connect to the server, you can start the game with your IP address instead of a map:

```
UDK.exe yourIPaddress
```

or from an already-running game, open the console and type either `open yourIPaddress` or `connect yourIPaddress`.

Comment: What is lan and listen server difference?

Comment: And are those lines runned in unrealscript or command line?

Comment: A listen server is a client that is also a server (so a server that is also able to play the game). A LAN server runs on your local network, whereas a "global" server has the potential to run over the internet (though I'm not sure if UDK supports that feature; you might look into the UDK forums or the documentation at http://udn.epicgames.com/).